# Citations go out of margins

Tags: line-breaking, citing

Some of my citations overflow into my margins. See below. I am wondering if there is any solution to this? I am using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

[image]

Comment: see the `breakcites` package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't `babel` also takes care of this?

Comment: possibly (but not as far as I know) I'm sure many of the citation packages have options for this now, breakcites has been around a while (since 1989 according to its comments)